# Power BI visuals tools for custom views

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to use [PowerBI-visuals-tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-tools). I am following the steps as per they mentioned. I am able to start the server from command line as below

[image]

But, in the browser, I am getting blank page. I saw the error in console coming as

```
Visual constructor undefined 
visual.ts:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read 
property 'element' of undefined     at new Visual (visual.ts:36)     at 
Object.create (visualPlugin.ts:8)     at (index):20
```

Can you please help why am I getting this error even I followed the steps from Github?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The debug visual is currently only available in the Power BI Service. You can navigate to https://app.powerbi.com/ and open any reports, then add the debug visual.

[image: debug-1]

You'll see the hello world visual if the server is up and running.

[image: debug-2]

For more details, please check out [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/tools/usage.md).

Comment: no need to do in locally?  then why https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals is for? can u please let me know.. as i am very new to this

Comment: You need to work both locally and with the service to develop your visual.  You develop the visual locally, with Visual Studio Code, for instance; but serve it up to the service via pbiviz start. After you run pbiviz start, every time you save your code, it will push the latest version of your visual that you are developing to the service so that you can see it through the debug visual that @Foxan Ng mentioned. You need to enable the debug visual via Settings/General/Developer. ...Check the box for "Enable developer visual for testing."

Comment: Hi @user6250770 does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.